# can we use Nasm for compiling 8086 microprocessor code?

Tags: nasm, emu8086

Can NASM compile 8086 Microprocessor code ?

So we are learning 'microprocessor' and our teacher sent us a 'windows' 8086 emulator link but I have Linux on my machine and unable to run using 'wine' as couple of videos showed. I have NASM-shell pre installed.

so i was wondering if we could somehow compile 8086 code using NASM.
I tried searching online but can't find definitive answer.

sorry, if i sound naive i don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   The `BITS 16` directive puts nasm into 16 bit mode to generate code for a 16-bit 8086 processor.